# Disabling request validation on Azure Websites

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

My node.js application runs nicely on my own machine, however, after pushing it up to an Azure WebSite using Git, I'm getting request validation problems.

Some of my requests are trapped by the IIS validation process. The fix is to add this to the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

I downloaded the web.config from the site\wwwroot folder of my website using FTP, added it to the repo, added the new element in the XML, and pushed it back up to Azure.

My web.config file seems to have been overridden by the default.

Is there a way of changing this behaviour? Or another way of turning off request validation? Or am I just being thick?

**UPDATE**

I take it all back, it seems to be express which is blocking the request. However, the question still stands as 'how do I customise my web.config?'

Comment: Have you checked if your web.config transformation is kicking in at publishing?

Comment: I expect this isn't happening. Have you got a link?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting a custom validation type? Like this:

```
  <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
               requestValidationType="MyValidator, MyAssembly"/>
```

And the class:

```
public class MyValidator : RequestValidator
{
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(HttpContext context, string value, RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey, out int validationFailureIndex)
    {
       validationFailureIndex = 0;
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately this is a node.js site. I'm certain this would work for asp.net. Changes I make to web.config don't seem to stick, which is the main problem

Comment: Could you post the exact error you're getting? And why do you think the changes don't seem to stick?