# Browse Azure website files?

Tags: azure, file-browser

Is FTP/SC the only means to browse and edit your Azure website?

Isn't there an online file explorer to be able to apply minor changes such as modifying the `web.config` file etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No online file explorer.
However minor changes to web.config, such as connection strings, app settings, default document and handler mappings are available via the "Configure" tab of the web site. For everything else, you should FTP.

Be careful with web.config, it has been seen that some changes are not allowed, though it is not documented. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630918/disabling-request-validation-on-azure-websites).